# layout_height doesn't work in layout file when using DataBinding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-databinding

I'm getting a list of users from a back-end server and I display in a RecyclerView. I have a layout file for each row. This is what I have tried:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data class="UserDataBinding">
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.example.myapp.User" />
    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/poster_path_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            //Other views
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

My goal is to display only the profile pictures. The problem is that even if I set the `layout_height` to `150dp`, the picture is displayed very small. Even if I increase the height nothing happens. How to set the CardView/ImageView to have a fixed height?

---

**Edit:**

I found the solution. I forgot to inflate the view. This line solved the problem:

```
ListItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
```

Comment: add your picture here.

Comment: Picture of what?

Comment: Image of profile pictures

Comment: can you give me a layout sample what do you want?

Comment: Sure, right away.

Comment: @BlackBlind See this https://i.ibb.co/zfWSnMD/Capture.jpg and I want to increase the `layout_height` so I can display 3 or 4 not 15.

Comment: give me full layout code

Comment: If I am not wrong so you want to show only 3 to 4 image instead of all.

Comment: @BlackBlind That's the full layout code. There is one more TextView but ignore that, it's not important. So I want 3 columns (as it already is) and 4 rows. Thanks

Comment: Are you using GridLayout

Comment: @BlackBlind Yes, that's correct.

Comment: show me your grid layout

Comment: I'm only setting `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"` and 
            `app:spanCount="3"` in my XML file. Is bad?

Comment: Please create an answer and answer your own question. Then accept this answer. It will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions and it may help others who have a similar problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks again David ;) But still no solution.

Comment: I'm sorry. In your question you say "Edit: I found the solution". I assumed that you found the solution. If not, please explain.

Comment: @DavidWasser Sorry, you're right. I was confused, I thought it was another question. Just added an answer right now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidWasser suggested, I added the solution as an answer to my own question. The problem was that I forgot to inflate the view. This line solved my problem:

```
ListItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion, I am adding an `XML` code where you can make a grid layout according to you with basic changes in `grid_layout_item`

```
 <GridView
            android:id="@+id/mainGridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#F3F3F3"
            android:columnWidth="200dp"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:paddingStart="-2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingEnd="-2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth">

        </GridView>
```

Look in my below code in CardView it has `90dp` as per your need you can change it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridviewdata"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/services"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/names"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/gridname"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin4"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Any further updates and help you can comment your problem in the comment section.
Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts but I need that layout file so I can use data binding. See I have declared that variable in it.

Comment: Do you want as per same as your layout?

Comment: if worry for data binding so you can copy data binding code and paste in my grid_item_class

Comment: Yes, I want it exactly. The problem is when I use data biding the `android:layout_height="150dp"` isn't considered at all. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Did you declare grid layout in your main layout?

Comment: Without binding, It will works perfect! What do you mean through "declare grid layout in your main layout"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198536/discussion-between-blackblind-and-lilian-sorlanski).

Comment: I solved it. See edited question. Thanks again anyway!